# Version tags added, but removed from question

Tags: support, tags

So I created a few new tags: [intellij-13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-13) and [intellij-12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-12)

And I assigned them to my questions [IntelliJ CSS autocomplete / Emmet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354319/intellij-css-autocomplete-emmet) and [IntelliJ 12 Android and Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710716/intellij-12-android-and-gradle) respectively.

Then, the tags got removed in [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19710716/revisions). My questions are:

1. Was I right to create these new tags? As IntelliJ versions differ wildly in terms of functionality and bugs
2. If so, why were the tags removed from the questions? I thought it more applicable to have a tag than have the version number in the title

Comment: Personally, I don't see how these tags are any different to the numerous Visual Studio version tags.

Answer (score 4):

That was me.  Sorry about that.  Sometimes I can be a bit zealous in removing new tags.

I'm not sure why I removed these given how long ago it was, but if you created them both on the same day it's very likely that I suspected that the questions that they were applied to actually had no *version-dependent* features that **required** a new tag.

Version tags are widely misused.  A lot of people use version-specific tags simply because they're using that *specific* version of some software product, without understanding that their question should also be tagged with the versionless tag of the same product in order to actually be *seen*.  As a result, some questions become hard to find, and questions that are hard to find also don't get timely, quality answers.

If you *must* create a version-specific tag, please be sure to read the [general policy on version tagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85358/135887).

The two tags you created seem to have survived, I didn't add them to my tag death watchlist.  It's probably safe to add them back.

If you feel strongly about those version-specific tags, I encourage you to monitor their use and ensure that their use corresponds to **specific features unique to that version** and that they're also tagged with the appropriate versionless tag for visibility.