# Handling opencv library version number tags

Tags: discussion, tags

This is a question about handling tag version numbers, considering [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv), a well-known computer vision C++ library.

That library has a rather classical versioning scheme: version 2 iterated through 2.1, 2.2, ... until the most recent 2.4.13. In the meanwhile, they released the 3.0 in 2015, and latest stable is 3.1.
(See http://opencv.org/downloads.html)

However, I notice we have a [opencv3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv3.0) tag, that has already 867 question. Some of these even [relate to release 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415530/). And we also have a [opencv3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv3.1).

So, what is the general policy for tag version numbers ? Show we create a [opencv3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv3.2) tag? And next a [opencv3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv3.3) tag? And then when do we stop?

It makes sense to have a specific `opencv3` tag, because the API changed quite a lot from release 2.X to 3.X, but my opinion is that the [opencv3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv3.0) should'nt have been created.

Is converting the tag [opencv3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv3.0) to [opencv3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv3) something that can be considered ? According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299613/193789):

> version-specific tags should only exist when:
>   There are major backwards-incompatible differences between versions, and
>   Both versions of the software continue to be used by the developer community

So I would say there is no need for [opencv3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv3.0) (neither 3.1)

For reference, I found some other related questions:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254779/193789
- [Should version specific tags be created for libraries](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286169)

Comment: Welcome, and congratulations. You have found the most annoying problems with tags, we are working hard [to fix this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147085/213575)

Comment: @Braiam Ok, fine, I assume this is irony. But now, what do we do ? Leave as is ? In your link, I read "[...] Remove & discourage version tags [...]". Is that ever done ?

Comment: You can try to enforce some policy, personally, I lean towards simplicity, the less tags the better.

Comment: @Braiam Exactly, that's my point here.